# Using parameters passed to stored procedure in query

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a sql query where I want to extract records older than 'X' number of days, here for eg its 7 days:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKMARK.MONITORING_TABLE WHERE inserteddatetime < (now() - '7 day'::interval);
```

I have to execute this query through a stored procedure passing in the configurable 'X' no of days as arguments.
The procedure is as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DELETE_REDUNDANT_RECORDS_STORED_PROCEDURE(days int)
RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
    rec_old                  RECORD;
    cursor_data CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM BOOKMARK.MONITORING_TABLE WHERE inserteddatetime < now() - '$1 day'::interval;

BEGIN
    OPEN cursor_data;
    // business logic for the procedure
    CLOSE cursor_data;
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This doesn't work as I am not able to use the placeholder for days in my query. How do we use the arguments passed to my query in this case.

Comment: Unrelated, but: why the loop what exactly are you doing inside that loop? A loop (cursor or not) is very often not the right tool - a set based approach is usually a much more efficient solution. But without seeing the real code in your loop this is hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an interval based on an integer, `make_interval()` is much easier to use than casting to an interval type.

Additional I wouldn't use a cursor, but a FOR loop based on a SELECT statement (maybe using `make_interval(days => $1)` works in the cursor declaration as well)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DELETE_REDUNDANT_RECORDS_STORED_PROCEDURE(days int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
  rec_old record;
BEGIN
    for rec_old in SELECT * 
                   FROM BOOKMARK.MONITORING_TABLE 
                   WHERE inserteddatetime < now() - make_interval(days => $1)
    loop
        raise notice 'records %', rec_old;
    end loop;
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I haven't added the entire Stored procedure logic intentionally, but this method solves my need